# Не могу решить проблему с индексами массивов в с# в проекте в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имею следующий код. Он создает кнопки в определенном месте с данными из массива.

```
public void CreateItemShop()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < dataSkins.Length; i++)
    {
       
        GameObject skinItem = Instantiate(prefabItemShopUI, Content.transform);
        skinItem.transform.GetChild(3).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = dataSkins[i].icon;
        skinItem.transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "" + dataSkins[i].price;

        Button buyButton = skinItem.transform.GetChild(6).GetComponent<Button>();

        buyButton.onClick.AddListener(() => OnClickBuyButtonSkin(buyButton, i));
     
        print(dataSkins[i].name);
    }

 }
```

Строка print(dataSkins[i].name); выполняется нормально. Индексы выводятся в консоль правильно. Чего не могу сказать о строке buyButton.onClick.AddListener(() => OnClickBuyButtonSkin(buyButton, i));
Данный метод возвращает лишь ошибку IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
   public void OnClickBuyButtonSkin(Button button, int i)
{
   
    Debug.Log(dataSkins[i].name);
    button.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: вам действительно требуется перевод фразы «Index was outside the bounds of the array»?

Comment: Я прекрасно понимаю перевод. Но абсолютно в неведении почему такая ошибка возникает. Ведь в одной строке (print(dataSkins[i].name); ) этот индекс есть, а в методе OnClickBuyButtonSkin уже за пределами.

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Классическая ошибка. Прочитайте про замыкания.
В Вашем случае нужно создать переменную, присвоить ей значение итератора и передать в лямбду.

```
    var buttonIndex = i;
    buyButton.onClick.AddListener(() => OnClickBuyButtonSkin(buyButton, buttonIndex));
```

Если коротко о причине, то лямбды будут выполнены после цикла. И в это время i везде будет одинаково и равно dataSkins.Length, что является не валидным значением для индекса.